# Is で here has the same function as によって?

Tags: grammar, nuances, particle-で

After a coffee store owner served coffee to his customers, he started with this line

> いいか? 豆っていうのは産地**で**全く味も違うし、挽き方**で**味も変わってくるんだ...

to show off his knowledge about coffee beans.

I'm not sure what kind で used in 産地で and 挽き方で. I can understand 産地で全く味も違う as "taste is differ depending on where they are produced." So, it seems to me that で here is almost same as によって (depending on...). Am I right here? What is the difference between で and によって?

Also, what is the meaning of てくる in 変わってくる? I don't think it has anything to do with movement or temporal change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct.
In both instances, で is synonymous--and interchangeable--with によって.
As far as I know, there is no difference between them. In fact, they are interchangeable when used in this kind of context.

変わってくる here simply means 変わる, with てくる indicating that it is 挽き方 that changes 味. (挽き方で味も変わってくる can be rewritten as 挽き方が味を変える with no semantic change.)

All in all, the quoted part can roughly translated as the following: Listen. The taste of beans change by provenance or grinding method.

Or when "全く" is reflected in English: Listen. Bean taste varies considerably from place to place, and changes by how they (beans) are ground.